# how can one avoid a private/weak copy of the STL when creating a shared library for LINUX

Tags: c++, linux

There are complains about my product regarding compile time at the customers site. The product creates C++ code and this code is being compiled into shared libraries at the customer site. When looking into an empty shared library created by this scenario, there is always a copy of the STL code contained. How can one avoid this, by importing it from a pre-compiled shared library, used by all the (at the customer site) generated shared libraries? E.g. imagine the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> MAP;
extern "C" const MAP *well_known_public_name(void) __attribute__((externally_visible));
const MAP *well_known_public_name(void)
{       static const MAP s{{"1", "2"}};
        return &s;
}
```

I know two ways of building this -- with and without -fwhole-program:

```
g++ -O3 -march=native -shared -fPIC test.cpp -std=c++11 -ffast-math -fwhole-program -DNDEBUG -funroll-loops
```

In both cases a copy of the std::map and std::string code is contained in the shared library. How can this be moved into another shared library AND avoided to be contained in this one?

Comment: `extern template`?

Comment: `I know two ways of building this -- with and without -fwhole-program` You build the shared library with -fwhole-program? `How can this be` Would you be able to provide simple compile commands you use to compile the source to shared library and an [MCVE] with commands that will show that the symbols of `std::map` and `std::string` are in the resulting library?

Comment: @KamilCuk What else than the contained code do you need to reproduce this? A makefile?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer for LINUX. I only wanted to demonstrate, that this problem can be solved on Windows since many years:

Code referencing the shared library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

template class __declspec(dllimport) std::allocator<int>;
template class __declspec(dllimport) std::vector<int>;
__declspec(dllimport) std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream&, const std::vector<int>&);

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{   std::vector<int> s(std::atoi(argv[1]));
    std::iota(s.begin(), s.end(), 0);
    std::cout << s << "\n";
}
```

code for the shared library:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template class __declspec(dllexport) std::allocator<int>;
template class __declspec(dllexport) std::vector<int>;
__declspec(dllexport)
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream&_rS, const std::vector<int>&_r)
{   _rS << "(";
    for (const auto i : _r)
        _rS << i << ",\n";
    _rS << ")";
    return _rS;
}
```